# What is the relation between $\|AB\|_1$ and $\|A\|_1 \|B\|_1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

For a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m}$ let

$$\|A\|_1 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k\sum\limits_{j=1}^m|A_{ij}|$$

be the sum of the absolute values of entries of $A$.

1. Given two matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m}$ and  $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, what is the relation between $\|AB\|_1$ and $\|A\|_1 \|B\|_1$?
2. It is known that for the Frobenius norm we have that $$\|AB\|_F \leq \|A\|_F \|B\|_F$$ Does the same inequality also hold for the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm?

My guess is that there is some $c$ depending on $k,m,n$ such that   $\|AB\|_1 \leq c\|A\|_1 \|B\|_1$.

Comment: All norms on finite dimensional spaces are equivalent. So $\|AB\|_1\le c\|AB\|_F\le c\|A\|_F\|B\|_F\le cd^2\|A\|_1\|\|B\|_1$. But it's unlikely these constants would be optimal. So the question could be edited as: "What's the best constant $c$..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We indeed have $\|AB\|_1 \leq \|A\|_1 \|B\|_1$. In particular, we have a sort of "Hölder's inequality" with $\|A\|_{\infty} = \max_{i,j} |A_{ij}|$: noting that $\|A\|_\infty \leq \|A\|_1$, we have
$$
\|AB\|_1 \leq \|A\|_1 \cdot \|B\|_\infty \leq \|A\|_1 \cdot \|B\|_1.
$$
In fact, $c = 1$ is the lowest number for which we have $\|AB\|_1 \leq c\|A\|_1 \|B\|_1$ for all $k,m,n$, as can be demonstrated by taking $A$ and $B$ to each be the matrix with a $1$ in the upper-left corner and zeros in all other positions.